# How to convert a string to an array with python?

Tags: python, serialization, json-deserialization

How to convert a string to an array with python?

I need to convert the value of items to an array.

I tried using json.loads, but it doesn't work.

Only the value of the ITEMS key is in string and it is exactly this value that I need to convert to array

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

```
"metadata": {
        "deleted": "false",
        "low_manual": "false",
        "canceled": "false",
        "items": "[{'descricao': 'ITEM1', 'amount': '200'}, {'amount': '3000', 'descricao': 'ITEm2'}]"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.

```
var = "metadata": {
        "deleted": "false",
        "low_manual": "false",
        "canceled": "false",
        "items": "[{'descricao': 'ITEM1', 'amount': '200'}, {'amount': '3000', 'descricao': 'ITEm2'}]"
    }

from ast import literal_eval

stringC = literal_eval(var['metadata']['items'])

stringC[0]
```

Comment: Please note that there are potential issues when using `ast.literal_eval` (e.g., it is possible for the python process to crash), if possible you should change how the data is being stored to use a more reliable form of serialization (E.g., [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html))

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is called "deserialization".  Deserialization is the process of converting from JSON text to an object (in this case Python-Object).  Serialization and Deserialization are best done with a library.

**Deserialization Python tool:**

[JSON Pickle Library](http://jsonpickle.github.io/)

What you want to do is install the library and import it into your project.  Then, you want to conduct a deserialization of the JSON text by using a command similar to the following:

```
obj = jsonpickle.decode(JSON text)
```

"obj" is now an object with the attributes of "deleted","low_manual", "canceled", and "items".  I believe "items" will contain an array of objects which you can access through the parent, "obj".

Comment: This is good advice about (de)serialization, but the for the given data, the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module would be sufficient and safer. Also, `obj["metadata"]["items"]` contains a string (probably the result of `repr`), not a literal list.

Comment: @DanielB thank you for the more expert insight and clarification.